# Box Sizing irregularity in Safari

Tags: css, safari, html-lists

I'm having difficulty getting an `<ul>` divided evenly in safari so that the inline `<li>` elements make up 100% of the width.

The html code is basically:

```
<ul>
    <li>red</li>
    <li>blue</li>
    <li>green</li>
    <li>orange</li>
    <li>purple</li>
</ul>
```

with css:

```
ul {
   list-style: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   width: 500px;
   background-color: #9999ff;
}
li {
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: inline-block;
   border-left: 1px solid #000;
   width: 20%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
li:last-child {
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

It seems like this would make 5 evenly spaces list elements which take up 20% (including borders) of the total width each.  Works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome but Safari leaves an extra 6 pixels or so at the end.  When I remove the box-sizing property then the list becomes too long.  I can't seem to make this simple thing work for the life of me.

Here's JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z2Xdf/7/

Answer (score 1):

It was rendering the wrong way for me in Chrome...at least using jsFiddle.

Inline-block puts some white space on the sides. Remove from li display:inline block and add

```
display:block;
float:left;
```

Also, move your background color to li from ul.

If you wanted to keep display:inline-block, you can apparently do this...

```
<ul><!-
    -><li>stuff</li><!-
    -><li>stuff</li><!-
-></ul>
```

but that seems like a hassle to type?

More ["hacks"](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)  here (check comments)...